# image_view giving glib errors and not displaying a window

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to launch image_view no window is display and I get these errors on stderr.

```
(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:8973): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(process:8973): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `(null)' in cast to `<invalid>'

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `(null)'

(process:8973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

What could be causing this? I'm running Gentoo and have installed ROS manually. On other systems I have not had problems and have not seen these error messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35784/image_view-giving-glib-errors-and-not-displaying-a-window/) by [Shum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2550/shum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess on Gentoo you have a much more recent version of glib. You will have to patch image_view manually. Did you try adding a call to g_type_init() somewhere in image_view as the error message suggests?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have the same problem running ROS Indigo on a Linux Mint 17 (trusty) image.

tobias@ros-engine:~/find_obj_2d_ws$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image _image_transport:=comprsed
init done
opengl support available

(image_view:43558): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(image_view:43558): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'

(image_view:43558): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

Can you tell how to patch image_view?

---

Originally posted by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) with karma: 156 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-06-25**:
Also getting the same problem. There must be some problem with Indigo version of image_view. Any tips?

**Comment by [weblucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/21400/weblucas/) on 2015-01-19**:
I also getting this erro with indigo